# How to create a bar graph from csv with dates as the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a bar graph from from a csv file my data looks like this:

```
06/14/12    SMB 12104560    8096373.6   1.5     1.08
06/15/12    SMB 10328540    8217192.68  1.26    1.24
06/18/12    SMB 5495294     8232792.78  0.67    0.85
```

I want the first column to be the x-axis and the last column to be the y-axis, Also if possible I just want to use the last 5 rows of data. This is what I have tried so far but 
Thanks

Edit New code:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(StringIO(etf + '.csv' ,dtype= [("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")]) , usecols=(0,-1))
x = numpy.arange(len(data))
pl1.bar(x,data["value"], width = 0.8)
p1.xticks(x+.4, data["date"])
p1.show()
```

new error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
import pylab as pl

datastr = """06/14/12    SMB 12104560    8096373.6   1.5     1.08
06/15/12    SMB 10328540    8217192.68  1.26    1.24
06/18/12    SMB 5495294     8232792.78  0.67    0.85"""

data = np.loadtxt(StringIO(datastr), 
                  dtype=np.dtype([("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")]), 
                  usecols=(0,-1))
x = np.arange(len(data))
pl.bar(x, data["value"], width=0.8)
pl.xticks(x+0.4, data["date"])
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but now I'm running into a problem reading the csv file I get an error ValueError: invalid shape in fixed-type tuple.

Comment: to read csv by loadtxt(), you just past the filename: `np.loadtxt(etf+'.csv', dtype=...)`

Comment: and the dtype should be `[("date", "S8"), ('value', 'f8')]`

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

Comment: to read from file, you don't need StringIO, just pass the filename: `data = numpy.loadtxt(etf+'.csv' ,dtype= [("date", "S8"), ("value", "f8")], usecols=(0,-1))`

Answer (score 0):

For any plotting purposes I would recommend using matplotlib.

There is an easy [example to plot a bar chart](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) - very similar to what you are using but sometimes it helps to start over from scratch.

Also, where exactly are you getting the TypeError?

Regarding the last 5 elements, you can always use the python's list splicing, e.g. `list[-5:]`

Comment: I am using matplotlib I cant get the date to be the x-axis. Also I am getting the type error on this line: ax.bar(date,relative, width = 10)

Comment: try checking the data types in all the arrays - just because something is a number in the csv does not mean that in does not need to be converted when read

Comment: I tried doing this as well (date.append((int((col[0])))) it didn't work either

Comment: well, col[0] is not an int, it is a string, so you should probably add an incremented integer there.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about matplotlib but this could be the problem:

```
date.append((col[0])) # <- appending a string
```

maybe you should try using

```
ax.set_xticklabels(...)
```

to get the string labels as it looks the 'date' list should not be a string.